# Can two different version control systems be mapped to one solution

Tags: version-control

I am working on a project where the project's version control is maintained by the client. The developers work off of the main repository and check in their code to the same. I have the responsibility of reviewing the code before it client sees it. The team checks in  Also, I do not have the access to the source control, because client won't allow that.
Can anyone please suggest how do I do handle this situation? Is it possible to maintain a local version control, mapped to the same folder as the client version control?

Thanks

Comment: Since you don't name the type of version control system, all I can offer are generalities.  You can check out the entire project, and let your developers copy from your checked out version.  Your developers would have to send their revised code to you.  You would verify the changes and put them back in your checked out project.  You would be responsible for all check ins from your checked out version.

Comment: I can go for subversion at my organization. The manual process of copying, merging and reviewing is what I considered as a last option. It is not safe plus I wouldn't know what all changes did the developers do each day. I would have to get that information too from them. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Since you mentioned Subversion, you can print out the change log to see what changes were made.  You would have to copy the changes to the client version control system.  Yes, you would still have to manually review all changes.  Wasn't that the point?